# Crash on Interface on data send to activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I got a main activity that will execute asynctask and then using interface to send data back to the activity which looks like the code below

Main activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_scroll);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    String type = "getProfile";

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    String username = pref.getString("username", null);

    RetrieveData retrieveData = new RetrieveData(this);

    retrieveData.execute(type,username);
}

public void sendData(String response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name="";
    String age="";
    String gender = "";
    String id = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        name = collegeData.getString("name");
        age = collegeData.getString("age");
        gender = collegeData.getString("gender");
        id = collegeData.getString("id");
        EditText MyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText14);
        MyName.setText(name);
        EditText MyAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText21);
        MyAge.setText(age);
        EditText MyGender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText22);
        MyGender.setText(gender);
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://192.168.12.252/"+id+"/profile.png").memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(imageView);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Asynctask

```
public class RetrieveData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    Context context;
    RetrieveData(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    private OnDataSendToActivity dataSendToActivity;

    public RetrieveData(View.OnClickListener activity){
        dataSendToActivity = (OnDataSendToActivity)activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String profile_url = "http://192.168.12.252/getprofile.php";
        String image_url = "http://192.168.12.252/imagelist.php";
        String type = params[0];

        if(type.equals("getProfile")){
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                URL url = new URL(profile_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result = null;
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(type.equals("getProfileImages")){
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                URL url = new URL(image_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("Image", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("Image", "UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result = null;
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dataSendToActivity.sendData(result);
    }
```

Interface

```
public interface OnDataSendToActivity {
    void sendData(String str);
}
```

When i execute the code, it crash on this line

```
dataSendToActivity.sendData(result);
```

and the error in android monitor is like below which i dont understand whats wrong

```
    --------- beginning of crash
03-24 04:12:42.518 20964-20964/com.example.lenovo.maidfriends E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.lenovo.maidfriends, PID: 20964
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.lenovo.maidfriends.OnDataSendToActivity.sendData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.lenovo.maidfriends.RetrieveData.onPostExecute(RetrieveData.java:119)
                                                                                    at com.example.lenovo.maidfriends.RetrieveData.onPostExecute(RetrieveData.java:33)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I assume that it says, it dont have any value in the result, but its not, there is something in the result.

Can anyone let me know whats wrong?

Comment: have you initialised dataSendToActivity variable.

Comment: @santoshgore You mean in asynctask? i had edit the code, can you please help me look thriough again

Comment: where is your sendMyData() method?when you are calling sendMyData , the object on which you are calling is null.

Comment: @santoshgore Sorry i paste the wrong error, kindly look my error message again

Comment: ok . dataSendToActivity  is null .so please verify that RetrieveData constructor getting called or not? because you are setting value of dataSendToActivity   in constructor.

Comment: Where are the `retrieveData.execute(type,username);` ?

Comment: I solve this issue by adding retrieveData.dataSendToActivity = this;

Answer (score 1):

You are not overriding RetrieveData function in Main Activity. You are just creating a new function with the same name.

Instead of calling Asynctask as:

```
RetrieveData retrieveData = new RetrieveData(this);
```

Use the following code:

```
RetrieveData retrieveData = new RetrieveData(new RetrieveData(){
public void sendData(String response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name="";
    String age="";
    String gender = "";
    String id = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        name = collegeData.getString("name");
        age = collegeData.getString("age");
        gender = collegeData.getString("gender");
        id = collegeData.getString("id");
        EditText MyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText14);
        MyName.setText(name);`enter code here`
        EditText MyAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText21);
        MyAge.setText(age);
        EditText MyGender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText22);
        MyGender.setText(gender);
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://192.168.12.252/"+id+"/profile.png").memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(imageView);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

});
```

Remove sendData() of Main Activity

Also in RetrieveData class, replace following code:

```
 public RetrieveData(View.OnClickListener activity){
        dataSendToActivity = (OnDataSendToActivity)activity;
    }
```

With:

```
public RetrieveData(OnDataSendToActivity activity){
    dataSendToActivity = activity;
}
```

Please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score -1):

Simple thing to call `sendData()` from `onPostExecute`:

```
MainActivity ma=new MainActivity();
ma.sendData(result);
```